# Cognito & DynamoDB: "not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource"

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

After following exactly the ["Getting started" guide for Amazon DynamoDB on Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html), I end up with all the right tables created, role policies, etc. and that code:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "eu-west-1:01234567-abcd-8901-efab-234567890123", // Identity Pool ID
        Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
);

AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
final DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);

final Book book = new Book("My new book"); // Simplified version of Book
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mapper.save(book);
        Log.v("Sync", "Book saved!");
    }
}).start();
```

Important note, the biggest (but unoticeable) difference with the tutorial is that I'm based in Europe so my region is `eu-west-1` (Ireland).

And yet, having followed everything correctly, I get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::012345678901:assumed-role/Cognito_BookUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:012345678901:table/Books (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 05OLSSM8F8EN15SO0JD8VELCNNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:709)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:385)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:196)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3257)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.updateItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:965)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1173)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:873)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1056)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:904)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:688)
    at com.davidferrand.books$4.run(MainActivity.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This "bug" is tricky and it took me hours to solve it. The guide assumes that you are in the `us-east-1` region, and that's also the default endpoint of the `AmazonDynamoDBClient` you create.

As soon as you have your database in a different region, **you must explicitly specify the region in when you create your `AmazonDynamoDBClient`**.

The best way to do it is:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1) // CRUCIAL
    .createClient(
        AmazonDynamoDBClient.class,
        credentialsProvider,
        new ClientConfiguration()
    );
```

Comment: what kind of policy did you use? is it about using userid policy of cognito? if yes, what is the userid?

Comment: I wasted hours on it. You saved me. Thanks